# ember-simple-auth session restore not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I have a custom authenticator which is really just extending the oauth2 authenticator so I can pass additional infomration to the API with my POST to /token.

All works fine. However, when you do a page refresh and the session tries to restore I am redirected to the login page and not authenticated.

The `restore()` method, if still within expiry and has a token should and does resolve with `data` however this does not authenticate the session.

Any ideas?

```
restore: function(data) {
var _this = this;
return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var now = (new Date()).getTime();
  if (!Ember.isEmpty(data.expires_at) && data.expires_at < now) {
    if (_this.refreshAccessTokens) {
      _this.refreshAccessToken(data.expires_in, data.refresh_token).then(function(data) {
        resolve(data);
      }, reject);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  } else {
    if (Ember.isEmpty(data.access_token)) {
      reject();
    } else {
      _this.scheduleAccessTokenRefresh(data.expires_in, data.expires_at, data.refresh_token);
      Ember.run(function() {
        log('returning restore')
        log(data) //shows my previous session data including access_token
        resolve(data);
      })
    }
  }
});
},
```

Comment: What does the session data look like before the refresh?

Comment: `{
  "secure": {
    "authenticator": "simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant",
    "access_token": "accesstokenstring",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 45000,
    "refresh_token": "",
    "expires_at": 1450131023288
  }
}`

Comment: Plus I also have some ofther data stored not in secure like the currentUser and the currentProfile

Comment: I also get this error  `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Comment: It seems the latter error was caused by me having a beforeModel hook in my application route, and callling ```this._super();``` without passing in `````this._super(transition)`````

Comment: I have upgraded to latest version from 0.8 and it seems to solve my problem

Comment: @LukeC where do you override `restore`?  In your custom authenticators extending `'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base'` ?